# Click activates background window

Tags: display, windows-8.1

I have been having problems with Windows 8 z-order. Two specific examples of this occur often for me:

1. Outlook reminder pops up over Outlook. I go to click on the reminder, but the window behind it (in this case the Outlook main window) is activated. It is though I clicked Outlook instead of the reminder. This doesn't happen every time.
2. Applications launch in the background, at the bottom of the z-order. Chrome does this often, but not all the time.

What would cause this, and is it something that can be fixed?

Comment: Do you have any shell extensions installed? Additional toolbars, taskbar mods etc.?

Comment: Not for Outlook.

Comment: So I guess you have such extensions for something. Try to disable them and check if the problem persists.

Comment: That is what this question is about. I've tried the obvious (Outlook and browser addins) and am interested in whether others have had these sorts of problems.

Comment: I think this is normal behavior.